# Break statement doesn't work

Tags: java

This is a small part of my code. Here the break statement doesn't work. The if condition is executed but the break statement takes the control to the start of the while loop. "assign" and "clsAssign" are two array list. "clustersRefGlobal()" is a function and I don't want to pass "assign" when it is empty. However due to break not working it is called even when "assign" is empty. I am not sure why break statement doesn't stop the while loop

```
   Wh:while (i < n) {
        System.out.println("Start");
        get = clustersRefGlobal(assign);
        clsAssign.add(get.get(0));
        assign = get.get(1);
        if(assign.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("Inside");
            break Wh;
        } 
        System.out.println("End");
        i++;
    }
```

Here is the output

```
Start

End

Start

Inside

Start

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at softwareClustering.DominantSetClustering.clustersRefGlobal(DominantSetClustering.java:54)
    at softwareClustering.DominantSetClustering.buildDominatSetClustering(DominantSetClustering.java:76)
    at trees.PrototypeSelectionTree.clustersRefLocal(PrototypeSelectionTree.java:214)
    at trees.PrototypeSelectionTree.clustersRefGlobal(PrototypeSelectionTree.java:180)
    at trees.PrototypeSelectionTree.buildTree(PrototypeSelectionTree.java:59)
    at trees.PrototypeSelectionTree.buildClassifier(PrototypeSelectionTree.java:235)
    at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.crossValidateModel(Evaluation.java:617)
    at trees.TestClassifier.main(TestClassifier.java:45)
Java Result: 1
```

The exception is because the "clustersRefLocal()" function is called with empty "assign" parameter. If any one knows whats the problem or what I am missing?

```
public double[] buildDominatSetClustering(int n) throws Exception {
    int i = 1;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> clsAssign = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> assign = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> get;
    for (int j = 0; j < data.numInstances(); j++) {
        assign.add(j);
    }
    Wh:
    while (i < n) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        get = clustersRefGlobal(assign);
        clsAssign.add(get.get(0));
        assign = get.get(1);
        if(assign.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("inside  "+assign.size());
            break Wh;
        } 
        System.out.println(assign.size());
        i++;
    }
    if(!assign.isEmpty())
    clsAssign.add(assign);
    double[] indexAssToClus = new double[data.numInstances()];
    int count = 0;
    for (ArrayList<Integer> a : clsAssign) {
        for (int k = 0; k < a.size(); k++) {
            indexAssToClus[a.get(k)] = count;
        }
        count++;
    }
return indexAssToClus;
}
```

This is the function in which the code exist

Comment: that is the strangest syntax i have ever seen

Comment: are we talking about Java?

Comment: It works for me in similar code. Perhaps you're calling the method twice? Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (In general though, just drop the label. Labelled statements in Java are *very* rare.)

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet - remove the labels on the loop. Unless you're using them to break a loop within a loop, in which case, the label on your break statement is wrong.

Comment: Even without the label it doesn't work and the method is called only within the while loop nor any where else

Comment: @Dropout - yes we are :-).  That is syntactically valid Java ... albeit that the use of a labelled break is both highly unusual, and unnecessary (here).

Comment: I added the function now may be it helps you to understand my mistake if any?

Answer (score 2):

The simple explanation to what you are seeing is that in fact the `break` is stopping the loop ... but the code around the snippet you have shown us is starting it again.

This will be apparent if you add a traceprint immediately before the labelled `while` statement.

---

> The exception is because the "clustersRefLocal()" function is called with empty "assign" parameter.

I suspect that you are confusing "empty" with `null`.  An empty string is a non-null `String` that has zero length.  If you try to test if a `null` String is empty by calling `String.isEmpty()` you will get an NPE.  The correct test for a non-null, non-empty String is this:

```
if (assign == null || assign.isEmpty()) {
    // null or empty ... bail out
    break;
}
```

Comment: Well, I understand that issue and its not about if it is null or empty. If the condition is true with assign.isEmpty() then why it take the control to start of the while loop and function "clustersRefLocal()" is called. What I am doing in the function is a separate story. The point is that if condition is true the loop should be terminated

Comment: >>My<< point is that that is NOT what is happening.  The loop >>is<< terminating, and somehow it is starting over again.  If you don't believe me, then prove me wrong ... by writing and posting an SSCCE that allows us to see for ourselves what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you simply reverse the logic:

```
 if(! assign.isEmpty()){
     i++;
 }
```

But failing that, check what is happening to your variable `i`:

Your check is for: `while (i < n)`

But the only place `i` is ever changed, it is incremented.

Comment: That won't exit the loop.

Comment: The loop doesn't exit anyway. But the simpler the logic, the easier it is to see that :)

Comment: Yes it will never exit loop

Comment: A break statement without a label would exit the loop. i going >=n would exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

labeling your loops and using `break label` is discouraged. (its like the goto and causes spaghetti code.)

Besides, it's not making sense here, since you don't have nested loops. You  can just change `break Wh;` to `break;`